# Can we see relationship between two index variable

Tags: regression, econometrics, economics

In multiple linear regression model can I use dependent variable as index (composite food security index) and also one independent variable as index. For example livelihood vulnerability index for every household with other determinants. Can I get the answer with proper reference?